# Graph and Markov Chain

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have the following code:

```
proc = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, {{0.6, 0.4}, {0.3, 0.7}}]

Graph[{"A", "E"}, proc, GraphStyle -> "DiagramBlue"]
```

How can I 'force' to show the percentage values (0.6, 0.4 etc) on each arrow? I can see the values when I mouse hover it. Thank you.

Comment: I did the following: 

<pre
values = {{0.6, 0.4}, {0.3, 0.7}};
proc = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, values];

Graph[{"A", "E"}, proc, GraphStyle -> "DiagramBlue", 
 EdgeLabels -> Table[values[i], {i, Length[values]}]];
/pre>

It is showing the entire 'matrix' instead of each value as the two solutions below. Any further idea, please?

Comment: Answers to your question were posted before you made this comment. I don't understand what your comment is, but if you want a different answer, I will try to amend mine...

Comment: @KellenMyers : I'm just trying to find a way more readable and simple to solve it. I already give an up to you and to kguler . As you can see, the Table can be used with EdgeLabels.

Comment: And, as I said, I have amended my answer to show you how to do that properly if that's how you want to generate your labels.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
proc = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, {{0.6, 0.4}, {0.3, 0.7}}]
h = Graph[{"A", "E"}, proc, GraphStyle -> "DiagramBlue"]
ToExpression@StringReplace[ToString@FullForm@h, "Tooltip" :> ".1"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You answer is more readable and can also be used with 'unlimited' number of percentages also. Thank you.

Comment: I will just point out, for the record, that no one's answer was incompatible with any larger system -- in some cases, explicitly so (e.g. my second answer) and in other cases after trivial and obvious modifications.

Comment: Right. All the answers are good. This one is more. Relax.

Comment: @LuizRobertoMeier Thanks. Anyway, I recommend waiting a few hours before accepting an answer. An open question always attract more attention and you may get more and better answers

Comment: @belisarius I appreciate your recommendation and I will do it.

Comment: @belisarius Would be nice if the numbers/percentages were slightly above the arrows/lines. But, I appreciate your help and I am satisfied. Thank you very much, again. Here is an example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Example

Comment: @LuizRobertoMeier `ToExpression@StringReplace[ToString@FullForm@h, "Tooltip" :> ".1"]`

Answer (score 12):

**Update:** Getting `EdgeLabels`  from `proc` and using them directly  in `Graph`:

```
Graph[vl = {"A", "E"}, proc, GraphStyle -> "DiagramBlue", 
 EdgeLabels -> Flatten[MapIndexed[DirectedEdge @@ (#2 /. MapIndexed[#2[[1]]
   -> # &, vl]) -> # &, proc[[2]], {2}]]]
```

[image]

Using `MarkovProcessProperties[proc, "TransitionMatrix"]` in place of `proc[[2]]` gives the same result.

---

**Original answer:**

```
proc = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, {{0.6, 0.4}, {0.3, 0.7}}];
g = Graph[{"A", "E"}, proc, GraphStyle -> "DiagramBlue"];

SetProperty[g, Sequence @@ (AbsoluteOptions[g, EdgeLabels] /. Tooltip -> 1/2)]
(* or Tooltip -> Automatic *)
```

[image]

Few more alternatives -- all give the same picture

```
g1 = Graph[{"A", "E"}, proc, GraphStyle -> "DiagramBlue", 
           EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> PropertyValue[{g1, e}, "Probability"]}]
```

Or

```
g2 = Graph[{"A", "E"}, proc];
edgeprobs = (Join @@ {# -> PropertyValue[{g2, #}, "Probability"]} & /@ EdgeList[g2]); 
Graph[{"A", "E"}, proc, GraphStyle -> "DiagramBlue",  EdgeLabels -> edgeprobs]
```

Or

```
g3 = Fold[SetProperty[{#, #2},
                EdgeLabels -> PropertyValue[{#, #2}, "Probability"]] &,
          g3, EdgeList[g3]]
```

An alternative way to get the probabilities associated with edges:

```
props = Properties /. AbsoluteOptions @ g
(* {"E" \[DirectedEdge] "E" -> {"Probability" -> 0.7}, 
    "E" \[DirectedEdge] "A" -> {"Probability" -> 0.3}, 
    "A" \[DirectedEdge] "E" -> {"Probability" -> 0.4}, 
    "A" \[DirectedEdge] "A" -> {"Probability" -> 0.6}} *)

props /. {"Probability" -> a_} :> a
(* {"E" \[DirectedEdge] "E" -> 0.7, 
    "E" \[DirectedEdge] "A" -> 0.3, 
    "A" \[DirectedEdge] "E" -> 0.4, 
    "A" \[DirectedEdge] "A" -> 0.6} *)
```

Answer (score 9):

From the documentation for `DiscreteMarkovProcess`, you can come up with this:

```
Graph[proc, GraphStyle -> "DiagramBlue", 
 EdgeLabels -> 
  With[{sm = MarkovProcessProperties[proc, "TransitionMatrix"]}, 
   Flatten@Table[DirectedEdge[i, j] -> sm[[i, j]], {i, 2}, {j, 2}]],
 VertexLabels -> {1 -> "A", 2 -> "E"}
]
```

I took the liberty of changing how the vertices are labeled (otherwise the edge label commands would become unnecessarily further complicated).

Considering that's how it's done in the documentation, I suspect this is the cleanest way to do it canonically. There may be a better hack that might pick apart the Markov process data structure and piece together a graph, but this is how Mathematica devs seem to have intended it.

**SECOND VERSION**

Based on comments following the question, perhaps a different approach would help.

This time I will try to be "constructive" in some sense. Let's start with the probabilities:

```
proc = {{0.6, 0.4}, {0.3, 0.7}};
```

Now, you want to create your edge labels as a table. Every individual edge label will be of the form:

```
DirectedEdge[2,2] -> 0.7
```

Since that is the (2,2) entry in your matrix of probabilities. To construct that table:

```
edge = Table[DirectedEdge[i, j] -> prob[[i, j]],
 {i, 1, Length[prob]}, {j, 1, Length[prob[[i]]]}];
```

Here we use `Length[prob]` etc. to make sure our indices are right, but you can also just do:

```
edge = Table[DirectedEdge[i, j] -> prob[[i, j]], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}];
```

That list, however, is still in an array/matrix format. So we flatten it:

```
edge = Flatten[edge];
```

Finally, we need some vertex labels to go with it:

```
vert = {1 -> "A", 2 -> "E"};
```

And now we are done:

```
proc = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, prob];
Graph[proc, VertexLabels -> vert, EdgeLabels -> edge, GraphStyle -> "DiagramBlue"]
```