# How to add the weights to the transition graph of a Markov chain?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, markov-chains

The following working program uses
[Graph and Markov Chain](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58560/graph-and-markov-chain)

```
P = {{1/2, 1/2, 0, 0}, {1/2, 1/2, 0, 0}, {1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4}, {0, 0, 
   0, 1}}; proc = DiscreteMarkovProcess[3, P];
Graph[proc, GraphStyle -> "DiagramBlue", 
 EdgeLabels -> 
  With[{sm = MarkovProcessProperties[proc, "TransitionMatrix"]}, 
   Flatten@Table[DirectedEdge[i, j] -> sm[[i, j]], {i, 2}, {j, 2}]]]

sm = MarkovProcessProperties[proc, "TransitionMatrix"]
sm == P
```

Since I couldn't make it work for larger matrices, I clarified in the last two lines that sm is just P. But, if I try to replace sm by P in the first part, all hell breaks loose. So, I tried copy paste changing just P to a larger matrix, but this does not work. Why?

```
P = {{0, 1/4, 1/2, 1/4, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/3, 0, 2/3,
     0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
   {0, 0, 1/4, 0, 3/4, 0}, {1/4, 0, 0, 0, 3/4, 0}};
P // MatrixForm
proc = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, P];
Graph[proc, 
 EdgeLabels -> 
  With[{sm = MarkovProcessProperties[proc, "TransitionMatrix"]}, 
   Flatten@Table[DirectedEdge[i, j] -> sm[[i, j]], {i, 6}, {j, 6}]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
P2 = {{0, 1/4, 1/2, 1/4, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/3, 0, 2/3, 0}, 
      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1/4, 0, 3/4, 0}, {1/4, 0, 0, 0, 3/4, 0}}; 

proc2 = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, P2];

tm2 = MarkovProcessProperties[proc2, "TransitionMatrix"];
```

You can specify the edge labels using patterns:

```
Graph[proc2, EdgeLabels -> {DirectedEdge[i_, j_] :> tm2[[i, j]]}]
```

[image]

***Why your code does not work:***

```
EdgeList @ Graph[proc2]
```

[image]

and the spec

```
With[{sm = MarkovProcessProperties[proc2, "TransitionMatrix"]}, 
 Flatten @ Table[DirectedEdge[i, j] -> sm[[i, j]], {i, 6}, {j, 6}]]
```

refers to non-existent edges (e.g, `1 -> 5` or `6 ->6`).

Using a simpler example: Compare

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3}, EdgeLabels -> {DirectedEdge[1, 2] -> 100}]
```

[image]

with

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3}, 
 EdgeLabels -> {DirectedEdge[1, 2] -> 100, DirectedEdge[2, 2] -> 50}]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

@kglr Thanks! Your code can be shortened a bit, since tm2 is precisely P, to

```
    P = {{0, 1/4, 1/2, 1/4, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/3, 0, 2/3, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1/4, 0, 3/4, 0}, {1/4, 0, 0, 0, 3/4, 0}}; 
proc = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, P]; 
Graph[proc, EdgeLabels -> {DirectedEdge[i_, j_] :> P[[i, j]]}]
```

The command RuleDelayed (:>, :>) seems very useful :)